# Size of Postgresql table - increased on table row or column?

Tags: postgresql

So I have a strange problem. Recently I came across a database structure that was something like this:

```
| salt @ 01:00 | salt @ 02:00 | salt @ 02:00 |
|:-------------|--------------|--------------|
|            0 |            3 |           2  |
```

Where each datestamp was a separate column. I didn't think such a structure was optimal, so I rearranged it to look something like this:

```
|    creation_time    |   salt   |
|:--------------------|----------|
| 2018-08-15 01:00:00 |        0 |
| 2018-08-15 02:00:00 |        3 |
| 2018-08-15 03:00:00 |        2 |
```

For some reason, this incredibly increases the size of the table. In one table, I went from having `3269 rows` in the previous table to `5142823 rows`, which is fine, but the size increased from `1048 kB` to `674 MB`.

So is this some kind of hack to reduce table size i.e. defining each creation_time as a column instead of including it in the row? Could I do anything to reduce the size?

Comment: The number of records increased by ~1500, and the storage space increased by ~600.  I don't see anything unexpected, or even undesirable, here.

Comment: Besides, column names are not stored in the table, while a timestamp uses 4 bytes.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. I just thought it was a strange way of structuring the table, but maybe it actually is optimal