# Why am I getting syntax error at or near "@"

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

When trying to join two tables and update one of them, I'm receiving an unexpected error from this function right here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsi.update_data(_creation_time int)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format($sql$
        UPDATE tsi.forecasts_%s a SET
        a."incidents @ 01:00" = b.n_incid,
        a."road @ 01:00" = b.n_roads
        FROM tgi_tmp b WHERE a.link_ix = b.link_id;
  $sql$,_creation_time);
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It gives me this error message:

```
syntax error at or near "@"
cidents @ 01:00" = n_incid,
        ^
```

Do anyone know why I'm getting this error? The tables do contain the mentioned columns, so that is not the problem. Is postgres having a hard time dealing with string-columns in an Execute-format?

Postgres version: 10.5
Simplified table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tsi.forecasts_%s (
    link_ix int PRIMARY KEY,
    "slipincidents @ 00:00" SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    "roadcoverage @ 00:00" SMALLINT NOT NULL,
);
```

and tgi_tmp:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tgi_tmp (
    link_id TEXT,
    n_road SMALLINT,
    n_incid SMALLINT
    CONSTRAINT tgi_tmp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (link_id)
);
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using column names like that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name saving space and no time to reformat to a better structure

Comment: @Jesper: Obviously, you are losing time this way. Very error prone. Consider legal, lower-case, unquoted names everywhere. *That* saves time. As for your question, missing minimum requirements: table definition, Postgres version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Added requirements. Had had a discussion about the structure before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893728/size-of-postgresql-table-increased-on-table-row-or-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for some reason when I'm not specifying the offset. Like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsi.update_data(_creation_time int)
 RETURNS VOID

    AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format($sql$
            UPDATE tsi.forecasts_%s a SET
            "incidents @ %s" = b.n_incid,
            "road @ %s" = b.n_roads
            FROM tgi_tmp b WHERE a.link_ix = b.link_id;
      $sql$,_creation_time, '01:00', '01:00');
    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

Weird it complaints about the @ doesn't do that for me. What however is wrong is specifying the table (alias) for the columns you are assigning to in the set. You should only specify the column names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsi.update_data(_creation_time int)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format($sql$
        UPDATE tsi.forecasts_%s a SET
          "incidents @ 01:00" = b.n_incid,
          "road @ 01:00" = b.n_roads
        FROM tgi_tmp b WHERE a.link_ix = b.link_id;
  $sql$,_creation_time);
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to debug your function, I get these error messages, one after the other:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text
> ERROR:  column b.n_roads does not exist
> ERROR:  column "a" of relation "tsi_forecasts_1" does not exist
> ERROR:  column "incidents @ 01:00" of relation "tsi_forecasts_1" does not exist
> ```

Each after fixing the previous error.
I arrive at this working version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tsi_update_data(_creation_time int)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format($sql$
       UPDATE tsi_forecasts_%s a
       SET    "slipincidents @ 00:00" = b.n_incid  -- don't table-qualify target cols
            , "roadcoverage @ 00:00"  = b.n_road   -- col names in q don't match
       FROM   tgi_tmp b
       WHERE  a.link_ix = b.link_id::int; -- your db design forces a cast
  $sql$, _creation_time);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I cannot reproduce your error:

> ```
> syntax error at or near "@"
> cidents @ 01:00" = n_incid,
>         ^
> ```

Which must be invoked by something that's *not* in the question, like outer double-quoting or special meaning of characters in your unnamed client program.

All that aside, it might pay to reconsider your naming convention and your db design. Use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers and matching data types (`link_ix` is `int` while `link_ix` is `text`).

Comment: It's probably true that there's some unknown configurations that's causing the problems. The db design is fortunately not my making, and is currently being restructured, but needed a quick patch :)